# Distinct prime multiples on an interval

Tags: nt.number-theory

Back to 1980, P.Erd\H{o}s and C. Pomerance asked in their paper "Matching the natural numbers up to n with distinct multiples in another interval" (see page 160 of the journal scan
http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/matching.pdf):

"Related  to  these  questions,  we  ask  if  there  is  a  large
constant  $c$ so  that in  any  interval  of  length  $cn$  there  are  $\pi(n)-\pi(n/2)$ distinct
multiples  of  the  primes  in  $(n/2,  n]$  (there  need  not  be  a  matching).  "

I am wondering if there is any progress on this question. Also, can we say anything if we require only some prime multiples to be present (e. g. we want to guarantee that there are distinct multiples of at least $O(n/\log n)$ primes from $(n/2, n]$)?

Comment: I am not aware of any direct progress on the question.  Indirectly, I am looking at a kind of complement, which is the distribution of integers coprime to a given integer.  My gut tells me that c does not exist for all n, but if k is the number of distinct prime factors of n, then there is a constant c so that intervals of length cf(k)n will have the distinct multiples requested. Here f(k) should be slow growing and subquadratic, say like k(log k)^2.  Gerhard "Gut Has Been Wrong Before" Paseman, 2013.01.22